# Quotient set of Normalizer by centalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H \leq G$. Why is the quotient group of the normalizer of $H$  by the centralizer of $H$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(H)$? I've tried i=finding this theorem, but I haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you have a homomorphism
\begin{align*}
N(H)&\longrightarrow \operatorname{Aut}H\\
g&\longmapsto (h\mapsto ghg^{-1})
\end{align*}
and the kernel of this homomorphism is the centraliser of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall conjugation is an automorphism. An automorphism $\sigma$ of a group $G$ is called "inner" if it is a conjugation map, i.e. for some $g \in G$, $\sigma_g(x) = gxg^{-1}$. You should check the subset of all inner automorphisms of $\textrm{Aut}(H)$ is indeed a subgroup.

Intuitively, if we quotient the normalizer by the centralizer, we get non-trivial automorphisms. Try to apply this information formally i.e. come up with a map.